# Task freezes the GUI

Tags: c#, winforms, task, freeze, taskfactory

I am trying to make create a function to get the source code from a number of pages. After each page is grabbed, I want to update a label on my form indicating the progress (1 of 5, 2 of 5, etc.).

However, no matter what I try, the GUI completely freezes until the `for` loop has ended.

```
public List<List<string>> GetPages(string base_url, int num_pages)
{
    var pages = new List<List<string>>();
    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i <= num_pages; i++)
        {
            UpdateMessage("Fetching page " + i + " of " + num_pages + ".");
            var page = new List<string>();
            var page_source = webGet.Load(url+i);
            // (...)
            page.Add(url+i);
            page.Add(source);
            pages.Add(page);
        }
    });
    task.Wait();
    return pages;
}
```

The call to this method looks like this:

```
List<List<string>> pages = site.GetPages(url, num_pages);
```

If I remove `task.Wait();` the GUI unfreezes, the label updates properly, but the code continues without the needed multidimensional list.

I should say that I'm very new to C#. What the heck am I doing wrong?

**Update**

As per Darin, I have changed my method:

```
public async Task<List<List<string>>> GetPages(string url, int num_pages)
{
    var pages = new List<List<string>>();
    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    for (int i = 0; i <= num_pages; i++)
    {
        UpdateMessage("Fetching page " + i + " of " + num_pages + ".");
        var page = new List<string>();
        var page_source = webGet.Load(url+i);
        // (...)
        page.Add(url+i);
        page.Add(source);
        pages.Add(page);
    }
    return pages;
}
```

And the call:

```
List<List<string>> pages = await site.GetPages(url, num_pages);
```

However, now I am getting this error:

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

But when I mark the method with async, the GUI still freezes.

**Update 2**

Woops! I seem to missed a piece of Darin's new method. I have now included `await webGet.LoadAsync(url + i);` in the method. I have also marked the method I am calling from as `async`.

Now, unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

> 'HtmlWeb' does not contain a definition for 'LoadAsync' and no extension method 'LoadAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlWeb' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've checked, I'm using .NET 4.5.2, and the HtmlAgilityPack in my References is the Net45 version. I have no idea what's going on now.

Comment: There is a single thread that updates the UI. If you block that thread with a `task.Wait()` then the UI can't update.

Comment: You missed the most important part from Darin's method: `await webGet.LoadAsync(url+i)`. Just because a method is marked as `async` doesn't automatically make it asynchronous.  If you don't await anything, it will run synchronously and will freeze the UI.

Comment: WinForms. Should I be using WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming WinForms, start by making the toplevel eventhandler `async void` .

You then have an async method that can `await` a `Task<List<List<string>>>` method. That method does not have to be `async` itself.

```
private async void Button1_Click(...)  
{ 
   var pages = await GetPages(...); 
   // update the UI here
}


public Task<List<List<string>>> GetPages(string url, int num_pages)
{
    ...
    return task;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I remove task.Wait(); the GUI unfreezes, the label updates
>   properly, but the code continues without the needed multidimensional
>   list.

That's normal. You should update your function so that it doesn't return the value but rather the task:

```
public Task<List<List<string>>> GetPages(string base_url, int num_pages)
{
    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        var pages = new List<List<string>>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= num_pages; i++)
        {
            UpdateMessage("Fetching page " + i + " of " + num_chapters + ".");
            var page = new List<string>();
            var page_source = webGet.Load(url+i);
            // (...)
            page.Add(url+i);
            page.Add(source);
            pages.Add(page);
        }
        return pages;
    });

    return task;
}
```

and then when calling this function you will use the ContinueWith on the result:

```
var task = GetPages(baseUrl, numPages);
task.ContinueWith(t => 
{
    List<List<string>> chapters = t.Result;
    // Do something with the results here
});
```

Obviously before accessing `t.Result` in the continuation you probably would like to first check the other properties to see if the task completed successfully or if some exception was thrown so that you can act accordingly.

Also if you are using .NET 4.5 you may consider taking advantage of the [async/await constructs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx):

```
public async Task<List<List<string>>> GetPages(string base_url, int num_pages)
{
    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    var pages = new List<List<string>>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= num_pages; i++)
    {
        UpdateMessage("Fetching page " + i + " of " + num_chapters + ".");
        var page = new List<string>();
        var page_source = await webGet.LoadAsync(url+i);
        // (...)
        page.Add(url+i);
        page.Add(source);
        pages.Add(page);
    }
    return pages;
}
```

and then:

```
List<List<string>> chapters = await GetPages(baseUrl, numPages);
// Do something with the results here.
```